# Python 3.6, Django 1.11, Windows 10, Gdal 2.2.4 not working

Tags: python, gdal, windows-10, django

I've been trying to find a solution to this issue, but couldn't find anything.
I've installed OS4GEOW using the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/install/#windows)

But I get the following error:

  `File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 49, in <module>
    lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found`

I've modified the C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py file, so it contains this line:
`lib_names = [str('gdal201'), str('gdal202'), str('gdal111'), str('gdal110'), str('gdal19')]`

instead of:

`lib_names = [str('gdal201'), str('gdal20'), str('gdal111'), str('gdal110'), str('gdal19')]`

`gdalinfo --version` returns: `GDAL 2.2.4, released 2018/03/19`

I also have `GDAL=="2.2.4"` python package installed.

My path contains:

`C:\Python36\Scripts\
C:\Python36\
C:\OSGeo4W\bin`

My `C:\OSGeo4W\bin` folder contains `gdal202.dll` which in details says 2.2.4 version.

But it still doesn't run, would be glad for anykind of pointers/help because I'm kind of lost with GDAL Python 3.6 combo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days I've remembered that Windows now has integrated linux environment.
All of my problems have been fixed, and I can recommend just installing Ubuntu via the Window Store and just install python/related packages there, I have my DB and IDE and files still outside the 'linux' environment and it works great and easy.

Answer (score 0):

According to the Docs, GDAL 2.2 is [not supported for Django 1.11](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/).

Try upgrading Django to Version >= 2.0 or downgrade GDAL to 2.1.

Comment: It is though :)

Comment: Are you sure? When I look at the Django docs for Django 1.11, GDAL 2.2 is not in the list (it does show up, however, if you change the docs version to django 2.0 or above). The link above takes you to the 1.11 version of the docs.